# angular frontend combine api url with frontend url

Tags: node.js, angular

I set api address in environment.ts and it was working fine, but suddenly it show this error

> localhost:4200 says Http failure response for
> http://localhost:4200/udagram-api-dev.eba-smxqzhkz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v0/feed:
> 404 Not Found

even if I set api address to empty string, it show this error

> localhost:4200 says
> Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/feed: 404 Not Found

Comment: Why are you appending the API address to the frontend address? Shouldn't it be `https://udagram-api-dev.eba-smxqzhkz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v0/feed`

Comment: I'm not appending it myself, but it happens by frontend and this is the problem I want to solve

Comment: the problem was I write api address with http not https, thanks Harun

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Happy coding!